# 'foreground' command for coloring is not working in feynMF

Tags: feynmf

I am trying to draw a Feynman diagram using the feynMF package where I wanted to put a specific color to a line and a blob. But even if I use the `foreground` command in `\fmf` and `\fmfv` environments, the color is not coming (it's the default black color). Below is the code I am using.

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=10pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, slashed, graphicx, xcolor, feynmf}%, feynmp}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,80)

\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}

\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}

% first vertex
\fmfdot{v1}
\fmflabel{V1}{v1}

% second vertex
\fmfv{d.sh=circle, d.fi=full, d.si=2thick, f=(1,,0,,0), l=V2}{v2}

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

If anyone can give me some idea of what's going wrong I will be very thankful.

Thanks and regards,
Saumyen

Comment: You can only get colour if you use MetaPost to generate the image instead of Metafont  (as it says in the manual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/feynmf).  But you have commented out the `feynmp` option.

Answer (score 1):

To get colour you have to use METAPOST instead of METAFONT.

As it says in the [manual](https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf):

> 2.5.4 **Color**
>
> If METAPOST is used for rendering the diagrams, vertices and arcs can be
> colored. The corresponding options give a warning
> message under METAFONT and are otherwise ignored.

So change your `\usepackage` line to:

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, slashed, graphicx, xcolor}
\usepackage{feynmp}
```

and then compile as recommended in the manual:

```
latex <yourfile>.tex
mpost feyngraph.mp  
latex <yourfile>.tex
dvipdf <yourfile>.dvi
```

if I do all that, then the OP input gives a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thruston. It worked with `feynmp` and `feynmp-auto`. Now it's coming good.

Comment: @Saumyen https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/15036